# What is the best way to organize the code for a full Taipy application?

Tags: performance, web, taipy

I'm new at Taipy, and I needed to understand what were the best practices to create a full Taipy application in the best possible manner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to organize your code is in a manner that works best for you. However, one way to do it would be:

- algos/algos.py
- config/config.py
- pages/
  page_1/
  page_1.py
  page_1.md
  …
- main.py

But the way to do it would be to is to the CLI of Taipy with this command: `taipy create --template default`